# Covariance in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, functional-programming, covariance

I'm learning [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/lecture), as I went through the lecture [Subtyping and Generics](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/lecture/81), I had a confusion about covariance:

Given: `NonEmpty <: IntSet` or `NonEmpty` is a subtype of `IntSet`

Is `List[NonEmpty] <: List[IntSet]` or Is `List[NonEmpty]` a subtype of 
`List[IntSet]` ?

And the answer is this makes sense since a List of non-empty sets is a special case of a list of arbitrary sets.

Does this answer imply that `List[NonEmpty]`is a subtype of `List[IntSet]`?

So I tried this:

```
val nonEmpty: List[NonEmpty] = null
val intSet: List[IntSet] = nonEmpty
```

Then I got a compilation error:

> Expression of type List[NonEmpty] doesn't conform to expected type
>   List[IntSet]

As I know generics are invariant in Java, are generics covariant in Scala 
or I have wrong understanding about convariance?

Edit:

Here are the definitions of `IntSet, NonEmpty, List`:

```
abstract class IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {...}

trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
```

Comment: This should compile (assuming you are using standard Scala `List`). What are the definitions of `NonEmpty` and `IntSet`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: I change to Scala List and it complies, but I don't understand why, aren't they both generic types.

Comment: `scala.collection.immutable.List[+A]` is covariant on `A` as denoted by the `+` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your definition of `List`; its type parameter is not prefixed with a `+` to indicate that the type parameter is covariant. Change it to this:

```
trait List[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should know is that

> In Scala, however, generic types have by default `nonvariant` (or, "rigid") subtyping

`covariance` means that

> if S is a subtype of type T, then should List[S] be considered a subtype of List[T]

`nonvariant` has another meaning that

> if S is a subtype of type T, then should List[S] not be considered a subtype of List[T]

The [document](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html) will help you. Just search the word `covariance`, then you will find the answer to your question.

Have a good luck